# How to find and replace box character in text file?

Tags: regex, text, utf-8, special-characters

I have a large text file that I'm going to be working with programmatically but have run into problems with a special character strewn throughout the file. The file is way too large to scan it looking for specific characters. Most of the other unwanted special characters I've been able to get rid of using some regex pattern. But there is a box character, similar to "□". When I tried to copy the character from the actual text file and past it here I get "�", so the example of the box is from Windows character map which includes the code 'U+25A1', which I'm not sure how to interpret or if it's something I could use for a regex search.

Would anyone know how I could search for the box symbol similar to "□" in a UTF-8 encoded file?

**EDIT:**

Here is an example from the text file:

"� Prune palms when flower spathes show, or delay pruning until after the palm has finished flowering, to prevent infestation of palm flower caterpillars. Leave the top five rows."

The only problem is that, as mentioned in the original post, the square gets converted into a diamond question mark.

Comment: Can you please provide sample input && output plz?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear where and how you are searching, although you could use the hex equivalent:

```
\x{25A1}
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/b84oBs/1

Comment: I think this is probably close but it's not the right hex value.

Comment: @ConnerM: It's difficult to say which character it is without knowing the actual character... maybe try `\x{FFFD}`, which would be `�`.

Answer (score 1):

The black diamond with a question mark is not a character, per se.  It is what a browser spits out at you when you give it unrecognizable bytes.

- Find out where that data is coming from.
- Determine its encoding.  (Usually UTF-8, but might be something else.)
- Be sure the browser is configured to display *that encoding*.  This is likely to suffice `<meta charset=UTF-8>` in the header of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using Notepad++ and this [website](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%EF%BF%BD&preview=entity). It's still not clear what encoding system the square is originally from, but when I post it into the query field in the website above or into the Notepad++ Conversion Table (Plugins > Converter > Conversion Table) it gives the hex-character code for the "Replacement Character" which is the diamond with the question mark.

[image]

Using this code in a regex expression, `\x{FFFD}`, within Notepad++ search gave me all the squares, although recognizing them as the Replacement Character.